# Empty HashSet becomes null on return

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Returning an empty `HashSet` from a function turns the object to null. What causes this behaviour and is there any way to work around it? I don't want to have to special case the empty set case everywhere (i.e. instead of a nice clean `if ($set.Contains(something))` now it has to be `if ($set -and $set.Contains(something))`).

```
function GetASet() {
    $someSet = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]
    $someSet
}

[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]]$set = GetASet
$set -eq $null # this is true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell [unrolls collections](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps/tree/master/Basic/Unrolled-collections) by default (although not very consistently). You need to hint it to explicitly return collection in your function:

1. `@($someSet)`
2. `,$someSet`
3. `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $someSet`

Comment: Oh I thought it did that just for native PowerShell arrays. So it basically does it for everything that implements IEnumerable or similar? Not a feature I'm that fond of when writing scripts although it certainly is convenient in the shell. `@($someSet)` doesn't work (weirdly enough, that's my usual solution for arrays) but `,$someSet` and the nice and explicit `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` does the trick.

Comment: @Voo I'm not sure about implementation details, there are many places where collections can be unrolled (pipeline, arguments, host input, etc...). But it's definitely not limited to built-in arrays. Since we're talking about the pipeline output, those lines look relevant: [pipelinebase.cs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/pipelinebase.cs#L502-L505). This is for PS Core, but I think PS for Windows does the same (just too lazy to dig in with decompiler).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your function

```
    function GetASet() {
        New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]
    }
```